# Gremlin DSL to mask g.V() with g.V().has()

Tags: groovy, gremlin, graph-databases, dsl, amazon-neptune

how can i write a strategy to replace g.V("id123") with g.V().has("id","id123") in gremlin.
I'm using JanusGraph as my graph DataBase.

Comment: I saw this also being discussed on the [Gremlin Users](https://groups.google.com/g/gremlin-users/c/yCnHbx-Op4o) list. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Actually, I was trying to create a subGraph strategy and bind it with traversal object g. As I'm not very familiar with groovy and gremlin so not sure how to create a strategy.

Comment: Using Strategy I'm able to transform g.V(id)  to g.V().has("entityId", id)
But is there a way I can remove id from gremlin output or replace it with entityId?
Without making changes at the serializer level?